# Why does a device appear in AWS console but not on AWS machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume, mount

I'm trying to attach and mount a volume to an AWS machine. I am starting the machine using Vagrant, and I have created in the Vagrantfile a block device called "/dev/sda2". After starting the machine, I see in the AWS console that the device is created:
[image]

As you can see, AWS knows the device exists. However, when I try to mount the device on the AWS machine, I get an error.

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/example_mount
mount: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist
```

In fact, the directory /dev/sda2 does not exist.

```
cd /dev/sda2
-bash: cd: /dev/sda2: No such file or directory
```

Here is lsblk output:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  10G  0 disk
├─xvda1 202:1    0   1M  0 part
└─xvda2 202:2    0  10G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  50G  0 disk
xvdi    202:128  0  50G  0 disk
```

Why do I see the device in the AWS console but not on the machine?

Comment: While it applies to EBS volumes read [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) to understand how to create a new file system and why the disk names are different.

Comment: Doesn't it seem like `/dev/xvdb` is an excellent candidate, here?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the one. I still find the renaming strange -- but that seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What linux are you using? Make sure your system doesn't see the drive differently, for example */dev/xvda2*?
If you can, please provide the *lsblk* command output.

Comment: I added lsblk output to the question. The disk "xvdi" looks suspiciously similar to /dev/sdi. Why would the disk be renamed without my knowledge?

Comment: I have seen similar question and relatively good answer in related post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47617/how-to-attach-new-ebs-volume-to-ubuntu-machine-on-aws/47909#47909

Comment: Another good explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679498/why-does-my-system-change-my-device-from-dev-sdj-to-dev-xvdj?rq=1